# cannot access private member declared in class 'Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer'

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, accelerometer

I have the following code:

**AccelerometerDelegate.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"

using Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer;
using Windows::Devices::Sensors::AccelerometerReading;

ref class AccelerometerDelegate sealed
{
public:
    double GetX();
    double GetY();
    double GetZ();
    AccelerometerDelegate();
    void GetCurrentReading();
private:
    Accelerometer ^ accelerometer;
    AccelerometerReading ^ accelerometerReading;
};
```

**AccelerometerDelegate.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "AccelerometerDelegate.h"

AccelerometerDelegate::AccelerometerDelegate()
{
    accelerometer = ref new Accelerometer();
}

void AccelerometerDelegate::GetCurrentReading()
{
    accelerometerReading = accelerometer->GetCurrentReading();
}

double AccelerometerDelegate::GetX()
{
    return accelerometerReading->AccelerationX;
}

double AccelerometerDelegate::GetY()
{
    return accelerometerReading->AccelerationY;
}

double AccelerometerDelegate::GetZ()
{
    return accelerometerReading->AccelerationZ;
}
```

The construct declaration is throwing a compile error:

```
Error   1   error C2248: 'Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer::Accelerometer' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Windows::Devices::Sensors::Accelerometer'
```

I am calling it within my Game class:

**Game.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "pch.h"
#include "CubeRenderer.h"
#include "AccelerometerDelegate.h"

ref class Game sealed : public Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkView
{
public:
    Game();
    ...    
private:
    AccelerometerDelegate ^ accelerometer;
    ...
};
```

**Game.cpp**

```
void Game::Initialize(CoreApplicationView^ applicationView)
{
    ...             
    accelerometer = ref new AccelerometerDelegate();
}
```

Do you know why this might be?

- **Accelerometer is built into a windows phone namespace: Windows::Devices::Sensors**
- **Its declaration is as follows:**

  ```
  public : ref class Accelerometer sealed
      Member of Windows::Devices::Sensors

  Summary:
  Represents an accelerometer sensor.

  Attributes:
  [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::DualApiPartitionAttribute(version = 100794368),
  Windows::Foundation::Metadata::VersionAttribute]
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a singleton that you have to retrieve using `Accelerometer::GetDefault()`

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer.getdefault).